# Osm2pgsql error: authentication method 10 not supported

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, pgadmin-4

I'm getting the following error when trying to import osm data using osm2pgsql.  I just installed pgAdmin4 today so it should all be up to date.

osm2pgsql version 0.92.0 (64 bit id space)

pgAdmin4 version 6.7

```
osm2pgsql -c -d osm -U postgres -H localhost -S C:\osm2pgsql-latest-x64\osm2pgsql-bin\default.style us-latest.osm.pbf
```

`Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: Connection to database failed: authentication method 10 not supported`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a fairly old version of `osm2pgsql`, which includes an even older version of `libpq` (like v 9.6). This version does not allow connecting to a postgres instance (PG10+) configured with the now standard `scram-sha` authentication method (how your password is hashed and saved).

So you have 3 options:

1. [download](https://osm2pgsql.org/download/windows/) a newer version of `osm2pgsql` (v1.6 at time of writing, which comes with libpq v12)
2. Reconfigure your database to use `MD5` instead of `scram-sha` (Do the opposite of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64316324/i-tried-to-change-postgresql-md5-to-scram-sha-256-and-i-get-fatal-password-authe/64317399#64317399))
3. Find a `libpq` for PG10 and replace the one in the `osm2pgsql-bin` folder (there are breaking changes after v10)

Comment: Curses! The env variables were pointing me to an old version in Osmosium.  I had downloaded the latest version but didn't do the math on the version number when I looked at it.  It's working now. Thank you.